# Defining your own abstract integer data type

Tags: haskell, data-structures

I got a task and have some problems with understanding. Task is to define: 
Type has three constructor: Zero (constant), Succ AbstractInteger (successor to abstract) and Pred AbstractInteger (predecessor abstract).
Could anyone just show me an example of defining, please? I really can't understand if it must contains value or not or how it is suppose to be.

```
data AbstractInteger = Zero | Succ (AbstractInteger) | Pred (AbstractInteger)
                         deriving(Show, Eq)
```

Something like this?

Comment: Looks good to me. You don't need to include parentheses around the `AbstractInteger` in your data declaration.

Comment: Firstly it was 'data AbstractInteger a = Zero | Succ (AbstractInteger a) | Pred (AbstractInteger a)' so i should have :)
But also i have to make it instance of Ord and Num so how it would be without a value?

Comment: I can tell you that *personally* I would write functions `fromInteger` and `toInteger` to translate between your data type and the standard Haskell `Integer` type, and then use the `Ord` and `Num` instances for `Integer`. But your professor may consider that cheating. Think about how you would define those operations recursively.

Comment: So am I right?
My defining is good and I don't need to do smth like this: 
Zero | Succ a (AbstractInteger a) | Pred a (AbstractInteger a)

Comment: You don't need to store any polymorphic data. An integer is not a container. — I would prefer `data AbstractInteger = Zero | Negative AbstractNat | Positive AbstractNat` with `data AbstractNat = One | Succ AbstractNat` because it has less redundancy; but your version will work too.

Comment: Thank you, guys.
One more question: 
Succ(Succ(Succ Zero)) in my version will it be equivalent to number 3 from Integer for example?

Comment: Yes it will. So will `Prec(Succ(Succ(Succ(Succ Zero))))`, which is the redundancy mentioned by @leftaroundabout.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I totally got it

Comment: If you don't take @leftaroundabout's suggestion, you probably will want to define your own instance for `Eq`. As @Tarmil pointed out, `toInteger (Succ(Succ(Succ Zero))) == 3` and `toInteger (Pred(Succ(Succ(Succ Zero)))) == 3`, however `Succ(Succ(Succ Zero)) /= Pred(Succ(Succ(Succ Zero)))` with the derived instance for `Eq`.

Comment: @Cirdec I think you're missing a couple of `Succ`s in your comment.

Comment: @Cirdec No, I won't because due to the task Pred and Succ can't be used in one number so Pred(Succ Zero) is incorrect. But thank you for your advice. It's useful

Comment: @leftaroundabout since you answered the question, perhaps you should post it as an answer?